# Getting "containers with unready status: []" error in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to deploy a Kubernetes Pod in AKS (I'm new to Kubernetes, so at this stage, I just want to create a container, deploy to Kubernetes and connect to it).

My Yaml file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec: 
  containers:
    - name: dockertest20190205080020
      image: dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io    
      ports:
      - containerPort: 443
metadata: 
  name: my-test
```

I've created the image in Azure Container Registry and, according to the CLI, successfully deployed it to Kubernetes.

After deploying, I used the following command:

```
kubectl get service
```

And it tells me there is no External IP to connect to.  I then tried:

```
kubectl describe pod my-test
```

Which gave the following errors:

```
 Events:
   Warning  Failed   4m (x2221 over 8h)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-27401563-2  Error: ImagePullBackOff
   Normal   BackOff  0s (x2242 over 8h)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-27401563-2  Back-off pulling image "dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io"
```

I then tried editing the deployment:

```
kubectl edit pods my-test
```

Which game me the error:

```
message: 'containers with unready status: [dockertest20190205080020]'
```

I'm not a little unsure what my next diagnostic step would be.  I get the impression there's an issue with the container or the container registry, but I'm unsure how to determine what that may be.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help.  The correct answer actually turned out to be a combination of the two answers: I didn't have permission, but I also hadn't specified the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here (most likely) - your AKS doesnt have permissions to pull images frmo you ACR (that's the default behaviour). You need to grant those ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks#grant-aks-access-to-acr)):

```
#!/bin/bash

AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP=myAKSResourceGroup
AKS_CLUSTER_NAME=myAKSCluster
ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP=myACRResourceGroup
ACR_NAME=myACRRegistry

# Get the id of the service principal configured for AKS
CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)

# Get the ACR registry resource id
ACR_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --resource-group $ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP --query "id" --output tsv)

# Create role assignment
az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role acrpull --scope $ACR_ID
```

Alternative is to just use a docker login secret (that article mentions that as well).

Example image in ACR:
[image]

image name would be

clrtacr.azurecr.io/dns:tag (or without tag for latest)

Comment: I had tried something similar to this, but I tried this and it made no difference.  I think you might be on the right lines with permissions, though.  When I run the dashboard, I get a series of errors such as: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard" cannot list services in the namespace "default"

Comment: dashboard is something completely different, just grant dashboard serviceaccount permissions

Comment: Thanks: the dashboard now works, and gives me a clearer (?) error: Failed to pull image "dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Comment: like i said, you need to grant aks permissions to acr, please read the answer

Comment: I've read, and tried your solution several times, but am still getting the same issue.

Comment: your image name is registryname.azurecr.io/imagename, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you know there is something wrong in your yaml file, or it just shows as you want for security. But I would show you here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec: 
  containers:
    - name: dockertest20190205080020
      image: dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io/image_name_and_version   
      ports:
      - containerPort: 443
metadata: 
  name: my-test
```

Also, as the error that you got shows, you don't have the permission to pull the image from your ACR.

On my side, I would be better to use a secret for pulling all the image from the ACR. You can create a service principal to achieve it. The steps would be like here:

```
#!/bin/bash

ACR_NAME=myacrinstance
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME=acr-service-principal

# Populate the ACR login server and resource id.
ACR_LOGIN_SERVER=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query loginServer --output tsv)
ACR_REGISTRY_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query id --output tsv)

# Create acrpull role assignment with a scope of the ACR resource.
SP_PASSWD=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --role acrpull --scopes $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --query password --output tsv)

# Get the service principal client id.
CLIENT_ID=$(az ad sp show --id http://$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --query appId --output tsv)

# Output used when creating Kubernetes secret.
echo "Service principal ID: $CLIENT_ID"
echo "Service principal password: $SP_PASSWD"

# Create the secret 
kubectl create secret docker-registry acr-auth --docker-server <acr-login-server> --docker-username <service-principal-ID> --docker-password <service-principal-password>
```

Then you can change your yaml file like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec: 
  containers:
    - name: dockertest20190205080020
      image: dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io/image_name_and_version   
      ports:
      - containerPort: 443
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: acr-auth
metadata: 
  name: my-test
```

Comment: I did not know there was an error in the YAML file.  How / where would I get the image name and version from?  Is it in the docker file, as I can't see anything there that's obvious?

Comment: @SmileyDev No, `dockertest20190205080020.azurecr.io` is an Azure Container Registry and you find the image name and version in it if you pushed your image to it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dim here, but how do I identify the image name?  Or if not identify the image name, is there a way that I can test if the image name exists in the container registry?

Comment: @SmileyDev Yes, you can use the Azure CLI command to see if the image exists in the ACR. Take a look at [Create a private container registry using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli).